# How can I run a FastCGI script in root url (/ - without path)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, fastcgi

I have created a simple application in Python/Flask, which has a home url (`www.site.com/`). I have acquired a HostGator **shared account** to host it, so I only have access to `.htaccess`, but no other Apache config files.

I setup a FastCGI script to run the application (following [these instructions](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/django-with-fastcgi)), but they require the URL to have a `/index.fcgi` or any other path. **Can I make the root path (/) be served directly by the FastCGI script?** Also, folders like `/static/` and `/favicon.ico` should be served by Apache instead.

What I have now as `.htaccess` is:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
DirectoryIndex index.fcgi

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.fcgi$ - [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.fcgi/$1 [R=302,L]
```

I'm not sure, but I think the Apache version is 2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI: You can check apache version with

```
apachectl -V  # or /<pathwhereapachelives>/apachectl -V
```

For the fastCGI setup, see if this link helps.  http://redconservatory.com/blog/getting-django-up-and-running-with-hostgator-part-2-enable-fastcgi/

Basically, if you want to run the script in `/`, you can use mod_rewrite to serve static files directly (as `/media` in the example below), and every other path being served by the WSGI script:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note that, as you are using Flask, you will have to override the `SCRIPT_NAME` request variable (as described [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/fastcgi/#configuring-apache)), otherwise the result of `url_for()` will be a string starting in `/index.fcgi/...`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#: optional path to your local python site-packages folder
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '<your_local_path>/lib/python2.6/site-packages')

from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from yourapplication import app

class ScriptNameStripper(object):
   def __init__(self, app):
       self.app = app

   def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
       environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = ''
       return self.app(environ, start_response)

app = ScriptNameStripper(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WSGIServer(app).run()
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: After a few modifications, this was the way to go. However, the application still appended `/index.fcgi` to every `url_for()` call (did I mention I'm using Flask?). But I found the `ScriptNameStripper` described in the official Flask site: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/fastcgi/#configuring-apache

Answer (score 2):

The Apache configuration I use for that (with comments explaining what each part does) is:

```
# Basic starting point
DocumentRoot /path/to/document/root

# Handle static files (anything in /static/ but also robots.txt)
Alias /static /path/to/document/root/static
Alias /robots.txt /path/to/document/root/robots.txt

<Location /robots.txt>
    SetHandler default-handler
</Location>

<Location /static>
    SetHandler default-handler
</Location>

# Handle the FastCGI program on the root
Alias / /path/to/my_fastcgi_program.fgi/

# Handle FastCGI
<Location />
    Options ExecCGI

    AddHandler fcgid-script .pl
    AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi

    Require all granted
</Location>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this solution uses directives that are not allowed in the .htaccess file, for example https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias